# ios direct photo post to instagram via api

Tags: ios, instagram

I have been researching the ability to direct post photos from an ios app to Instagram via their API.  I am aware that a few application have this ability such as the WhoSay for talent app.

Does anyone have insight into how to make this happen with than going directly to Instagram?

Comment: There are plenty of existing discussions here about posting an image to Instagram. Do some searching a try something. If you have a specific question about a specific attempt at a solution, update your question with the proper details.

Comment: I have done extensive research and searching on this topic and the results are fairly vague and incomplete.  Most of the discussions end with the same conclusion that it can't be done effectively without getting access directly from Instagram.  My posting this question was to see if there are any other definitive methods or knowledge available here.  I do thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The [Document Interaction](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/#document-interaction) section on the iPhone Hooks page of the Instagram Developer Documentation describes how this is achieved.

Read the documentation, and have a go at implementing it. Then if you are still having difficulties, as [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) said, post a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The iPhone hooks will not allow you to post directly to a users photo stream.  They take you out of your app and into Instagram, which is what I am trying to avoid.  I an trying to post directly to a users account stream and not be taken out of my app to do so.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AlanW I don't think that's possible. You mention the WhoSay Talent app does this though. Are you sure it's completely automated? If so, perhaps they have a special relationship with Instagram who have given them additional API capabilities.

Comment: With WhoSay Talent App it is totally automated, I am a user of that service.  I think you are correct that they have a special relationship with Instagram.  Just was hoping that someone here would have a work around for this functionality.  Thanks for reply.